# TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined at Object.j [as render] (angular-datatables.min.js:6)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, datatables

I am using angular-datatables.min.js for datatable and I am facing this error, I tried a lot but not able to resolve. Can some one please help me on this?

```
App.controller('DailyTaskListController', ['$scope', '$http', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder', function DailyTaskListController($scope, $http, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder){

    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
        .withOption('ajax', { 
             url: 'dailytask/getMoreRecord',
             type: 'GET', 
             dataSrc: 'data'
            })  
        .withOption('processing', true)
        .withOption('serverSide', true)
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers');

    $scope.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName')
    ];
    }]);
```

and table in which I have used it,

```
<table  datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table table-bordered table-striped row-border hover">
```

js files which i have used in same sequence

```
<script src="${bowerResouceUrl}jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<link href="${bowerResouceUrl}datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="${bowerResouceUrl}angular/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script src="${bowerResouceUrl}angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="${bowerResouceUrl}angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script> 
<script src="${bowerResouceUrl}angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is `datatables` injected into module?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .withOption('ajax') you may not use  datatable="ng" but just  datatable in your table tag.